# distortion coefficents with opencv camera calibraton

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm writing in visual c++ using opencv library. I used calibrateCamera function with a checkboard pattern to extract intrinsic, extrinsic and distortion values. The problem is that I don't know how to use the distCoeffs matrix (1x5) on my 2D points on the CCD. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: read the first section of the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant portion of the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html) is

Tangential distortion occurs because the image taking lenses are not perfectly parallel to the imaging plane. Correcting this is made via the formulas:

```
x_{corrected} = x + [ 2p_1xy + p_2(r^2+2x^2)] 
y_{corrected} = y + [ p_1(r^2+ 2y^2)+ 2p_2xy]
```

So we have five distortion parameters, which in OpenCV are organized in a 5 column one row matrix:

```
Distortion_{coefficients}=(k_1 k_2 p_1 p_2 k_3)
```

You can also use [undistort](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-undistort), [undistort points](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-undistortpoints), or [initUndistortRectifyMap](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv-initundistortrectifymap) combined with [remap](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html#cv-remap)